# Seconds since date (not epoch!) to date

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a dataset file with a time variable in "seconds since 1981-01-01 00:00:00". 
What I need is to convert this time into calendar date (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss). 
I've seen a lot of different ways to do this for time since epoch (1970) (timestamp, calendar.timegm, etc) but I'm failing to do this with a different reference date.

I thought of doing something that is not pretty but it works:

```
time = 1054425600

st = (datetime.datetime(1981,1,1,0,0)-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(st+time)
```

But any other way of doing this will be welcome!

Comment: Off the top of my head... that doesn't happen to be an Excel file with Excel-epoch format or some such? A library for parsing Excel files should be able to decode this correctly...

Comment: @deceze - It is a netcdf file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

t0 = datetime(1981, 1, 1)
seconds = 1000000
dt = t0 + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
print dt
# 1981-01-12 13:46:40
```

Here `t0` is set to a `datetime` object representing the "epoch" of `1981-01-01`. This is your reference datetime to which you can add a `timedelta` object initialised with an arbitrary number of seconds. The result is a `datetime` object representing the required date time.

N.B. this assumes UTC time